# Pass paramater with Onclick Event

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering how to pass custom vars with a onclick event.

I have several buttons in a form. Any of this button opens a dialog, including some checkboxes. When you click on the OK button, I have to check what checkboxes have been checked and do someting else (hope you understand what I want). The dialog and any stuff are created programmatically.

So I create the checkboxes and the OK button:

```
CheckBox[] chkModules = new CheckBox[lstFailedSteps.Count];
int chkCounter = 0;
foreach (int intFailedStep in lstFailedSteps) 
{
    chkModules[chkCounter] = new CheckBox();
    chkModules[chkCounter].Text = dicStepDescriptions[intFailedStep];
    chkModules[chkCounter].AutoSize = true;
    chkCounter++;
}

chkCounter = 0;
foreach (CheckBox check in chkModules)
{
    chkCounter += 25;
    check.Checked = true;
    pnlRestart.Controls.Add(check);                
}

Button btnOkay = new Button();
btnOkay.Text = "OK";
btnOkay.Click += btnOkay_Click;
```

Okay, and now I want to the the method, that is called when clicking on the button, pass the chkModules array.

Thx in advance!
Cheers
Alex

Comment: Ok! And what have you tried to do so? Did you for example loop over all checkboxes in `pnlRestart.Controls` in the `btnOkay_Click` handler and check their checked state?

Comment: Possible solution would be - as I found out just right after posting this - to make a static class var for the Checkbox array and access it from the click method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastes way is creating anonymous event for your button click:

```
btnOkay.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
   //implement your click logic here or call method that accepts CheckBox[] as parameter
};
```

this way all local variables are in scope of event.